# Forwarding subdomain.example.com to localhost:25565 (for free)

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, tunnel

### Objective

How can I forward subdomain.example.com to localhost:25565?

- without paying for a service
- without router admin access
- without exposing more than port 25565 of localhost
- using Google Domains
- localhost is Windows 10

### Reasoning

I am running a Minecraft server on my desktop that runs on port 25565. I want my friends to be able to connect to the server using a subdomain of a domain I already own. Currently, I am using ngrok 
and my friends connect to `0.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:[redacted]`. However, the port keeps changing which is discouraging them from playing as they have to ask me for the port number every time it changes (at least once a day). I understand why ngrok do this, I'm just using the free tier after all. However, the paid version of ngrok that provides a static subdomain, costs nearly as much as it would to pay for a minecraft server.

### Attempts

**Temporary subdomain forward**: can only forward to a http destination and ngrok and minecraft require TCP.
**Dynamic DNS**: I followed [Google's tutorial](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083) with a Windows port of DDclient but, as far as I can tell, DDNS does not support forwarding to a port.
**Other tunneling services**: localtunnel (serverless.social) does not appear to support TCP; localxpose and others charge for TCP; serveo and others are now offline. In essence, I can't find any suitable alternatives to ngrok but I'm still looking.

I am also talking to the Google Domains support team but thought I'd ask to see if anyone knows a way already.